# The best way to implement authentication for a REST API

Tags: mobile, rest, login

We develop social-based applications for mobile. Every application consumes RESTful API web-services. When I implement login I usually store the username and password somewhere on device. Then I send them and as a response I get access to my profile. But I also know there's another way to do this.

One somehow generates a token with a particular algorithm, and then send it instead of the username and password to gain access.

How should I implement that? Should I send this token along with every other request than login?

Comment: That's *authentication*, not *authorization*. Authentication = prove that you are who you say you are. Authorization = prove that you are allowed to do what you requested.

Comment: I was just going to add the same comment to the answers! +1 to you @tdammers
I have edited all the contents so googling authorization doesn't bring you here

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several way how to implement *authentication* in RESTful context, and it is more safe to send only tokens instead of login/password: you could easy make tokens to be invalid by timeout or by some other criteria, and ask user to re-authenticate.

For example [authentication REST requests using HMAC](http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html). In this approach, client will have *public* and *secret keys*. To all requests that require *authentication*, you should add *publiс key*, and use *secret key* to calculate hash of your request

```
var myRequest = "https://myserver/resource?publicId=12345&param=value";
var requestHash = hmac_implementation(myRequest);
myRequest = myRequest + '&hmac=' + requestHash;
```

Now server could identify request by *public key* and calculate *requestHash* itself. If both hashes are equal, then user is authorized.

Btw, you also have to use https to secure communication over a computer network — this will dramaticaly reduce number of possible problems.

Answer (score 9):

oAuth is the standard for this but there are more solutions.

Don't try to implement security, tokens etc. all by yourself since that's a difficult and risky topic. Take for example a look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574868/securing-my-rest-api-with-oauth-while-still-allowing-authentication-via-third-pa